# Two dimensional fourier transform computation

Tags: fourier-analysis

I have to compute the two dimensional fourier transform of the following function:
$f(x,y,z) = \frac{x}{(x^{2}+y^{2}+z^{2})^{5/2}}$

the paper that i'm following defined the two dimensional fourier transform of a function $g(x,y,z)$ as:

$\hat{g}(k_{1},k_{2},z)=\frac{1}{2\pi}\int \int g(x,y,z) e^{ik_{1}x+ik_{2}y}dxdy$

any idea on how to proceed? 
I'm also interested in the procedure that it is required to obtain the fourier transform, as I have to apply it to other functions.

It might be useful to say that the the authors also give an example, in particular given:
$g(x,y,z) = \frac{1}{(x^{2}+y^{2}+z^{2})^{1/2}}$

the fourier transform according to the definition they gave is:
$\hat{g}(k_{1},k_{2},z)= \frac{1}{k_{1}^{2}+k_{2}^{2}}e^{-kz}$

i'm quite clueless to be honest...